# Why do we need logical quantifiers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm studying set theory, and sometimes my professor uses the quantifier $\forall$, and sometimes not. For example, the Axiom of Extensionality is stated as $\forall X,Y (X=Y \iff \forall z(z \in X \iff z \in Y))$
. Why do we need "$\forall z$"? I think $z \in X \iff z \in Y$ clearly makes sense and have the same meaning. In the class, we proved $U-(\bigcup_{i \in I} {A_i}) = \bigcap_{i \in I}{U-A_i}$ by
$$x \in (U - \bigcup_{i \in I}{}A_i) \iff x \in U \land \lnot(\exists i \in I (x \in A_i )) \iff x \in U \land \forall i \in I (x \notin A_i) \iff \forall i \in I (x \in U \land x \notin A_i) \iff x \in \bigcap _{i \in I}{U-A_i}$$

which did not use the quantifier.

Comment: Leaving out $\forall z$ in your first example makes it horribly ambiguous. $\forall X,Y(X=Y\Leftrightarrow (z\in X\Leftrightarrow z\in Y))$ could be read equally as saying for any $z$ and any $X,Y$, $X=Y$ precisely when $z$ is in both $X$ and $Y$, or in neither, which is false. In fact it's more likely to be read this way than your intended meaning.

Comment: As Malice's comment illustrates, moving a quantifier generally changes the meaning of a statement. The proof sketch you mention is short for a more formal argument like "Let $x$ be arbitrary; prove $P(x)$; conclude $\forall xP(x)$".

Comment: We need quantifiers to express the difference between "for all" and "some". Sometimes, there is the practice of omitting universal quantifier, leaving it implicit; but this only if we have no ambiguities. If we write the equivalence $(x^2-1)=(x+1)(x-1)$, we are asserting it "for every $x$". If we write the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$, we are not asserting that it holds for every $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omiting the **leading** universal quantifiers is a convention, but it can lead to confusion depending on the context. Say we have both forms of the following statement :

1. $\forall x \ \forall y \ (x \in y \Longrightarrow y \notin x)$
2. $x \in y \Longrightarrow y \notin x$

Imagine we're in a situation where this statement is needed. Also imagine that in this context we have a set that we named $x$ and another named $y$.

With form 1., no ambiguity. But with form 2., a machine would just see a very weak statement, mere folklore about our sets $x$ and $y$ (and nothing beyond that).

Now, if you suppress a **non-leading quantifier**, it's even worse. e.g. take the example you gave, the two statements have a totally different meaning :

1. $\forall X,Y (X=Y \iff \forall z(z \in X \iff z \in Y))$
2. $\forall X,Y (X=Y \iff (z \in X \iff z \in Y))$

   1. says the correct thing : "any two sets $X$ and $Y$ are equal iff they contain exactly the same elements"
   2. takes a $z$ from the context and asserts : ""any two sets $X$ and $Y$ are equal iff whether one contains $z$, the other does, too."

All in all, don't be lazy, make the quantifiers explicit! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let X = {y,z}, Y = {z} and y /= z.
Even though z in X iff z in Y, does X = Y?

Answer (score 0):

- In words, the definition of set equality reads like this

> ***Whatever*** (set) $X$ and $Y$ may be,
>
> $(X = Y)$ iff [***whatever*** (object) $x$ is a member of  $X$ is also a member of  $Y$, and
>   reciprocally]

- You need the $\forall$ quantifier to express these " whatever".

It can be recalled that this definion amounts to equating  set identity to reciprocal incluson, and you need a universal quantifier to express inclusion.

- Also, you need the $\iff$ operator to express " reciprocally".